# Using Nmap to port scan

Tags: networking, server, nmap, netstat

I'm trying out `Nmap` and have encountered a problem. Before anything, I would like to tell you that I am using this on my own laptops at home :)
When I use `Nmap <target_IPAddress>` it shows me that the other laptop has 8 tcp ports open. However when I check on the other laptop with `netstat -a` to see if it's true a lot more ports appear, why? Shouldn't the exact same 8 tcp ports appear on the target host?

Comment: You should try zenmap. It's a GUI for nmap.

Comment: I do have Nmap GUI, but it gave me the same results

Comment: I was only pointing out zenmap as an easier way to use nmap... not because it answered your question. To your question, on the other laptop, note if there's a difference between using 127.0.0.1 (localhost) vs the real IP (192.168.x.y).

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include full output of `nmap` and `netstat -a`. Without them it'll be hard to impossible to answer your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 4):

Nmap does not scan all 65535 TCP ports by default. Instead, it scans the 1000 most-common port numbers according to empirical data gathered in 2008 with minor updates. If your computer is using some of the 64535 remaining ports, it will not show up in Nmap's output. You can add `-p 1-65535` or the equivalent shorthand `-p-` to scan all port numbers

Nmap also does not scan UDP ports by default. You can add `-sU` to add the UDP protocol. It will also only scan 1000 ports by default, but `-p-` will work to solve that as well. Note that because UDP services are not required to respond to arbitrary datagrams, UDP scanning is often very slow.

The other possibility is that you are misreading the output of `netstat`. Only ports in the `LISTEN` state are open. Others, such as `ESTABLISHED` can be outgoing connections or other things.